# A two variable function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $z=f(x,y)=\sqrt{(36-4x^2 -9y^2 )}$

So the way in the book is to find the ${\cal D}f$ and ${\cal R}f$ (which is the range of the function on the two domain function)

So they multiplied the whole function by negative and then they move $36$ to the other side of the equation, then you get $4x^2+9y^2\le 36$

The last step which quite confused me is 
They somehow divide $4x^2$ by $9$ and $9y^2$ by $4$ so the last step would be $$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}\le 1$$

I hope it's clear

Comment: What exactly is your question? The first inequality divided by 36 gives the second which is an ellipse equation in standard form.

Comment: @LutzL i do understand but , where the 4,9 come from ? Under the x,y ?

Comment: From $36=4·9$ or $4/36=1/9$ etc.

Comment: @LutzL that was helpful thanks